# Current R environment + packages = docker container

Tags: r, docker

Is there a way to take my current system and `docker-it'? I have some code for a paper and want to be able to make it as easy to reproduce as possible. However, I have a lot of packages and an old version of R. Is there a simple way to create a Dockerfile based my R console when all the packages I have are loaded in etc?

I'm new to using Docker.

Comment: Have you looked at https://rocker-project.org/ ?

Comment: I wonder if `renv` might be simpler to incorporate here. The tutorials I've encountered on setting up an R environment in docker typically describe a workflow that is more oriented to building up from scratch, installing each package you'll need. (vs. starting from your existing setup.) https://colinfay.me/docker-r-reproducibility/

Comment: @JonSpring `renv` is good but doesn't insist you use a specific R version (or install one locally as it does with packages). Over time old package versions may become incompatible with new R versions. So to ensure reproducibility docker is better. But I agree, much easier if you start from scratch. I've found myself writing a dockerfile manually with the MRAN versions of the output from `installed.packages()`. It would be great if there was an easier way!

Comment: @JonSpring just checked and it seems like MRAN is being discontinued soon. Might be better to just build a docker from scratch and try to migrate my code